# JEST : How to test for adding data to object

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am very new to reactjs, js and Jest. Please excuse me if it is a very basic question.

I want to write a unit test for the below. Can anyone please help me. Consider me as just starting with jest.

```js
class xyz {
  storingRepo: Object;

  constructor() {
    this.storingRepo = {};
  }

  storeProduct(a: string, b: string) {
    const key = `${a}_${version}`;
    this.waitingProductsRepo[key] = true;
  }
}

export default new xyz();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`xyz.ts`:

```js
class xyz {
  storingRepo: Object;

  constructor() {
    this.storingRepo = {};
  }

  storeProduct(a: string, b: string) {
    const key = `${a}_${b}`;
    this.storingRepo[key] = true;
  }
}

export default new xyz();
```

`xyz.test.ts`:

```js
import xyz from './xyz';

describe('62045858', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(Object.keys(xyz.storingRepo)).toHaveLength(0);
    xyz.storeProduct('a', 'b');
    expect(xyz.storingRepo).toHaveProperty('a_b');
    expect(xyz.storingRepo['a_b']).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The outcome for the test with a coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62045858/xyz.test.ts (9.997s)
  62045858
    ✓ should pass (3ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 xyz.ts   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.815s
```